# Installing Jenkins-X on GKE

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

This may sound like a stupid question, but I am installing Jenkins-X on a Kubernetes cluster on GKE.  When I install through Cloud Shell, the `/usr/local/bin` folder I am moving it to is refreshed every time the shell is restarted.

My question is two-fold:

1. Am I correct in installing Jenkins-X through Cloud Shell (and not on a particular node)?
2. How can I get it so the `/jx` folder is available when the Cloud Shell is restarted (or at least have the `/jx` folder on the path at all times)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am running jx from the Cloud shell

1. In the cloud shell you are already logged in and you have a project configured.  To prevent jx to re-login to google cloud/project use the following arguments

   ```
   jx create cluster gke  --skip-login=true --project-id projectId
   ```
2. download jx to ~/bin and update $PATH to include both `~/bin` and `~/.jx/bin`. Put the following to `~/.profile`

   ```
   if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
       PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
   fi

   PATH="$HOME/.jx/bin:$PATH"
   ```

   The `.jx/bin` is the place where JX downloads helm if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Shell VMs are ephemeral and they are discarded shortly after the end of a session.  However, your home directory persists, so anything installed in the home directory will remain from session to session.

I am not familiar with Jenkins-X.  If it requires a daemon process running in the background, Cloud Shell is not a good option and you should probably set up a GCE instance.  If you just need to run some command-line utilities to control a GKE cluster, make sure that whatever you install goes into your home directory where it will persist across Cloud Shell sessions.